# drawing a diamond inside a square usnig java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am having some trouble while using swing to draw a diamond inside a square.
My code is this,please some one have a look at it and let me know if you can provide a fullfunctional code which is working in creating a diamond inside a square.
The code is:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyDrawing extends JPanel
{
  static int width=250;
  static int height=250;
  static int x=0;
  static int y=0;
  private void doDrawing(Graphics g) 
  {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);

        //for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) 
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, width,height);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-45));
        System.out.println(Math.toRadians(-45));
        x=0;
        y=height/2;
        System.out.println(y);
        width=(int)Math.pow(Math.pow((width/2),2)*2,0.5);

        height=width;
        System.out.println("width:"+width+"height:"+height);
        g2d.drawRect(y, x, width,height);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
}
```

Comment: "swing", not "swings"

Comment: not sure about your requirement , but cant you show a diamond image within the square ??

Comment: No i need to create a diamond inside square.Basically the entire program is about nesting squares inside eachother.So one huge square outside with another square rotated 45 degrees nested inside it and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the the diamond inside the sqaure, simply 
 1.  Draw a rectangle
 2.  Rotate the rectangle about its center.

```
Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(20, 20, 50, 50);
g2.draw(rectangle);
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.PI/4, rectangle.getX() + rectangle.width/2,    rectangle.getY() + rectangle.height/2);
g2.draw(transform);
```

Comment: the code that you wrote also is nt working.The diamond is still outside the square.

Comment: Deepak,ur code is still not working.g2.draw(transformed) should be g2.draw(transform) which also gives en error.

Comment: Got my code working,needed to make a change by first translating the point and then rotating it.Anyways thank you all for ur help.